# Add javascript slider to BigCartel custom page

Tags: javascript, html, slider, bigcartel

I'm trying to add a slider with javascript (no plungins) to one of my custom pages on Bigcartel. I have ran the codes in Codepen and it seems to work fine. However, I can't seem to make it work on my page in big cartel. The arrow buttons are under the slide instead of on the left and right side of the slide, and I can't see the navigation "dot" under the slide either.
This is the code in html:

```
    <div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/ye3zh6ygyw55z0j/space1.jpg?raw=1" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/n7i41xgs9fclfjq/space2.jpg?raw=1" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/lz6pbim2kyo6lsy/space3.jpg?raw=1" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/r8efjzjuow7i720/space4.jpg?raw=1" style="width:100%">
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 


</div>

<script>
  var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex += n));
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex = n));
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

This the CSS:

```
    * {box-sizing: border-box}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 900px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

This is the page in Bigcartel:https://www.mellowsheng.com/test

And here is the how the slider should look in Codepen: https://codepen.io/jennnyt/pen/rNepEJa

Comment: Your CSS is not loaded. When I inspect .slideshow-container, there is no specific styling applied. Also, your console states that there is an unexpected '<'.

Comment: As it's a Bigcartel site, I needed to add the CSS on the bottom of their theme stylesheet. I can see it when I use the Inspect Element on my browser. I also saw the error of "an unexpected '<'", but I can't find it??

Comment: Your Javascript script contains HTML <br> en <p> tags, you can check it if you click on the console error

Comment: I see them and although it doesn't show on the editor of big cartel, I just took out all the line spaces in between and now the error is gone! Thank you Thomas! Do you have any idea why the navigation buttons (left and right) are under the slider instead of over the slider? And I also can't see the "dot"s that are supposed to be under the slider.

Comment: No problem! The arrows are also rendered with paragraph tags ( <p> ) surrounding them. This probably messes up the intended styling. Try to get rid of the extra tags here as well.

Comment: I found a </br> under the arrows and deleted it. And somehow now the slider works for screen less than 668px wide but as soon as I expand my browser the arrows are back under the slider and the dots are gone? I feel like I'm sooo close to make it work and I really appreciate all your help!